# Can I force Outlook to display email text at a certain font size?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts

Is it possible to set a minimum font size for displaying incoming email messages? The old CTRL-+ trick does nothing in Outlook.

Save my weary eyes!

Comment: Outlook version? In 2010 its possible

Comment: Outlook 2003 & 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's possible to set minimum size, but fastest way to increase font size when reading mail (although not permanently) is to use Ctrl + mouse scroll wheel.